# How to change metabase's access port on linux?

Tags: linux, port, metabase

I have a problem to change the metabase's port on linux

the ways described in https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/operations-guide/running-the-metabase-jar-file.html , but i'm not clearly understand what I must do

[the page's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONqh3.png)

after that the tutorial directed to https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/operations-guide/environment-variables.html , but still i'm not clearly understand

if there are any other solution, please let me know, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Metabase, but the documentation you linked to says:

> You can use another port than 3000 by setting the MB_JETTY_PORT environment variable before running the jar.

Therefore, I would try running the following command in my Bash shell to set the environment variable for that shell:

```
export MB_JETTY_PORT=12345
```

Then, in that same shell, I would run whatever command is used to start the JAR file.

You can run `echo $MB_JETTY_PORT` at any time to check the value of that environment variable, or run `env` to see all your environment variables.

Alternatively, if you prefer, Bash has syntax for temporarily setting an environment variable just for a single command.  The syntax is:

```
MB_JETTY_PORT=12345 your_command_here
```

If you're not using Bash, your other shell probably has similar ways to set the environment variables.

Comment: that works, thank you very much

Comment: Great.  Please click the checkmark to accept this answer and also upvote it if you can.

Comment: yeah i'm sorry I forget